# if statement numerical confusion in bash/sh

Tags: bash, shell, conditional-statements, sh

I've been arguing with this code all morning.  It finally dawned on me, upon reading TL;DP that my if statements may be confusing output redirection with a comparison.

The code in question is:

```
#!/bin/sh
...
if [ $DEBUG_LEVEL > 2 ]
then
  echo "I made it here"
  echo "DEBUG: created run_all_somatic_SNV_steps" >>$LOG
fi
```

Is my if statement confusing stderr redirection with what I want it to do? (compare a variable to the number 2)

Comment: show the code that assigns a value to DEBUG_LEVEL (please). good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For general shell:

```
if [ $DEBUG_LEVEL -gt 2 ]
```

(But that will fail if `DEBUG_LEVEL` has never been set.)

More bash-specific, and a lot nicer:

```
if (( DEBUG_LEVEL > 2 ))
```

Answer (score 1):

try this test construct:

```
[ $DEBUG_LEVEL -gt 2 ]
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I've been ready to quit programming and become a bounty hunter.